# Multer only writes one file from req.files to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm creating a simple page with a form to upload images and other data to a Sql Server database. My server is built with Node.js and express, I'm using Sequelize to connect to the database, and I'm using multer to get the req.files.

I'm new to multer, so I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm trying to upload three images from the form with multer, read the buffers from the files objects in req.files, use .toString() on those buffers, and then write those base 64 strings to a Sql Server database with Sequelize. The problem is that it only writes the string for the last item in the req.files array. It doesn't matter which one it is, but it only writes the last one The output to the console from Node.js says that it's writing all three strings to the database, but when you look at the table there is no value in the column. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll paste the code below, please let me know if more information would help.

Thanks in Advance for all your help!

Here's my route:

```js
'use strict';

var Event = require('../models/Event');
var fs = require('fs');
var clc = require('cli-color');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var Sql = require('sequelize');
var sql = new Sql('events_page', 'eventsUser', 'p@ssw0rd1', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

module.exports = function (router) {
  router.route('/createevent')
  .post(upload.array('images', 3), function (req, res, next) {
    sql.sync()
    .then(function () {
      Event.create(req.body)
      .then(function (newEvent) {
        newEvent.update({
          eventHeaderImage: req.files[0].buffer.toString('base64'),
          eventBackgroundImage: req.files[1].buffer.toString('base64'),
          eventSliderImage: req.files[2].buffer.toString('base64')
        })
        .then(function (eventWithPics) {
          res.redirect('/admin');
          
        });
      });
    });
  });
  
 };
```

Here's my server:

```js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var clc = require('cli-color');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var time = new Date();

var dbRouter = express.Router();
var adminRouter = express.Router();
require('./routes/db-routes')(dbRouter);
require('./routes/admin-routes')(adminRouter);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use('/', dbRouter);
app.use('/', adminRouter);

app.listen(port, function () {
 console.log(clc.cyanBright('server started on port ' + port + ' at ' + time));
});
```

Here's the schema for my event table:

```js
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Sql = require('sequelize');
var sql = new Sql('events_page', 'eventsUser', 'p@ssw0rd1', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

var Event = module.exports = sql.define('Event', {
  eventName: Sql.STRING,
  eventLocation: Sql.STRING,
  eventStartDate: Sql.DATE, //the start date...
  eventEndDate: Sql.DATE, // the end date...
  eventHeaderImage: Sql.TEXT, //bas64 string of header image
  eventBackgroundImage: Sql.TEXT, //image to appear on event slide on homepage
  eventSlideUpText: Sql.TEXT, //slide up text for future events page
  sponsorsHeading: Sql.TEXT, //heading for sponsors section
  sponsorsParagraph: Sql.TEXT, // paragraph below heading on sponsors section
  eventSliderImage: Sql.TEXT, //image for front page slider
  homepageBulletOne: Sql.STRING,
  homepageBulletTwo: Sql.STRING,
  homepageBulletThree: Sql.STRING
},
{
  getterMethods   : {
    eventUrl: function () {
      return this.eventName.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase() + '-' + this.eventStartDate.getFullYear();
    }
  }
});


Event.sync({force: false});
```

And finally here's the HTML:

```html
<form action="/createevent" id="createEventForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventName">Event Name</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventName" name="eventName" type="text submit" placeholder="Event Name" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventLocation">Event Location</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventLocation" name="eventLocation" type="text submit" placeholder="Event Location" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventStartDate">Start Date</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventStartDate" name="eventStartDate" type="date" placeholder="Event Start Date" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventEndDate">End Date</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventEndDate" name="eventEndDate" type="date" placeholder="Event End Date" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventHeaderImage">Header Image</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventHeaderImage" name="images" type="file" placeholder="Header Image" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventBackgroundImage">Future Page Image</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventBackgroundImage" name="images" type="file" placeholder="Image for Future Events Page" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventSlideUpText">Future Page Text</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventSlideUpText" name="eventSlideUpText" type="text submit" placeholder="Text for Future Events Page" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newSponsorsHeading">Sponsor Tab Heading</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newSponsorsHeading" name="sponsorsHeading" type="text submit" placeholder="Heading for Sponsor Tab" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newSponsorsParagraph">Sponsor Tab Intro Paragraph</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newSponsorsParagraph" name="sponsorsParagraph" type="text submit" placeholder="Intro Paragraph for Sponsor Tab" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newEventSliderImage">Image for Homepage slider</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newEventSliderImage" name="images" type="file" placeholder="Image for Homepage slider" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newHomepageBulletOne">Homepage Bullet One</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newHomepageBulletOne" name="homepageBulletOne" type="text submit" placeholder="Heading for Sponsor Tab" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newHomepageBulletTwo">Homepage Bullet Two</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newHomepageBulletTwo" name="homepageBulletTwo" type="text submit" placeholder="Heading for Sponsor Tab" />
        <label class="col_4" for="newHomepageBulletThree">Homepage Bullet Three</label>
        <input class="col_8" id="newHomepageBulletThree" name="homepageBulletThree" type="text submit" placeholder="Heading for Sponsor Tab" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button class="medium" id="createEventButton" type="submit">Create Event</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the strings were too long. When I started storing the file names and getting the images with links instead of base64 strings it worked.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Explanation:

In your route file, you have:

```
.post(upload.array('images', 3)
```

this means that you send by form one input file field, where user can select up to three files. But you in HTML create three equal input file fields. Therefore only one is send to your server.

### Solution:

In your HTML form make different input file upload, for example:

```
...
<input class="col_8" id="newEventHeaderImage" name="headerImage" type="file" placeholder="Header Image" />
...
<input class="col_8" id="newEventBackgroundImage" name="backgroundImage" type="file" placeholder="Image for Future Events Page" />
...
<input class="col_8" id="newEventSliderImage" name="sliderImage" type="file" placeholder="Image for Homepage slider" />
```

And in your route file:

```
...
.post(upload.fields([{ name: 'headerImage', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'backgroundImage', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'sliderImage', maxCount: 1 }]), function (req, res, next) {
sql.sync()
.then(function () {
  Event.create(req.body)
  .then(function (newEvent) {
    newEvent.update({
      eventHeaderImage: req.files['headerImage'][0].buffer.toString('base64'),
      eventBackgroundImage: req.files['backgroundImage'][0].buffer.toString('base64'),
      eventSliderImage: req.files['sliderImage'][0].buffer.toString('base64')
    })
...
```

I don't run this code, It is concept